# Is there any reference or material about the preseed file of MaaS Fast Installer?

Tags: maas, preseed

These days, I have tried to assign IP address to a node using the fast path installer (curtin).

In automatic installation procedure, we can assign a ip address to the primary network interface using preseed file. In the case of Debian installer, there are some materials how to make preseed files. So, I could assign a ip address using Debian installer.

But, In fast installer, there are few references about the way to modify fast installer preseed files.
I found the Adam Stoke's blog, it is very helpful but It didn't make me clear.

Using preseed files, I'd like to assign the ip address and download a script files through the specific URLs (late-command, wget) automatically.
So, If there are some materials explaining how to make curtin preseed files, please let me know.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/636837/are-there-examples-of-commissioning-scripts for a more complete answer

Answer (score 0):

The fast installer does not use preseed at all.  It deploys a pre-installed image.  That is why it is faster.  I do not believe there is any way to do the customization you are looking for with the fast installer.

As for how to modify preseed files when using the default installer, you should be able to find what you need here: https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/development/preseeds.html

Mark